# Java AWT Robot mouseMove(x,y) fails on Windows 10

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I am having an issue that has been reported here
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196031

I demonstrate the problem in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BerTofDwRUw

Essentally, robot is just moving the mouse to random coordinates. I tried running it in a loop until the current mouse coordinates match the desired ones, however that still does not work.

```
for(int count = 0;(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() != a.getXCoord() || 
    MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() != a.getYCoord()) &&
    count < 1000; count++) {
    if(count == 999) System.out.println("Maxed");
    robot.mouseMove(a.getXCoord(), a.getYCoord());
```

}

This will always max out, even with a loop count of 1000.
Is there a different class that can be used for mouse clicks? Any external libraries? Is there a way to apply the patches/fixes listed in the openjdk thread?

Comment: `Essentally, robot is just moving the mouse to random coordinates.` -  A video showing how your code reacts doesn't tell us anything. If you want to test the mouseMove(..) method, then test it with hard coded values or a loop where the values are well defined. The code you posted now doesn't tell us anything since we have no idea what your "a" variable is or what the values returned from the methods are. Those methods could be the cause of the problem. So post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem and then people using Window 10 can test the code.

Comment: It occurs with any usage of mouseMove(). I could make a program right now to move the mouse using mouseMove(500,500) and it will go to some other coordinate. It is not an issue in my code. It is a documented bug with robot

Comment: `I could make a program right now to move the mouse using mouseMove(500,500) and it will go to some other coordinate` - then do it. Don't post complicated, incomplete code that we can't understand or verify. When demonstrating a problem the code should be as simple as possible so it is easy to understand.